# Django Exclude Model Objects from query using a list

Tags: django, django-models

Having trouble with my query excluding results from a different query.

I have a table - Segment that I have already gotten entries from. It is related
to another table - Program, and I want to also run the same query on it but I want to exclude
any of the programs that were already found during the segment query.

When I try to do it, the list isn't allowed to be used in the comparison... See below:

```
query = "My Query String"
        
segment_results = Segment.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=query)|
    Q(author__icontains=query)|
    Q(voice__icontains=query)|
    Q(library__icontains=query)|
    Q(summary__icontains=query) ).distinct()

# There can be multiple segments in the same program
unique_programs = []
for segs in segment_results:
    if segs.program.pk not in unique_programs:
         unique_programs.append(segs.program.pk)
   
program_results = ( (Program.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(library__icontains=query) |
        Q(mc__icontains=query) |
        Q(producer__icontains=query) |
        Q(editor__icontains=query) |
        Q(remarks__icontains=query) ).distinct()) &
        (Program.objects.exclude(id__in=[unique_programs])))
```

I can run:

```
for x in unique_programs:
   p = Program.objects.filter(id=x)
    print("p = %s" % p)
```

And I get a list of Programs...which works
Just not sure how to incorporate this type of logic into the results
query...and have it exclude at the same time.  I tried exclude keyword,
but the main problem is it doesn't like the list being in the query - I get an
error:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'.

Feel like I am close...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, I was not comparing objects correctly in the filters, so
the correct statement would be:

```
program_results =  (Program.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(library__icontains=query) |
        Q(mc__icontains=query) |
        Q(producer__icontains=query) |
        Q(editor__icontains=query) |
        Q(remarks__icontains=query) )&
        (Program.objects.exclude(id__in=Program.objects.filter(id__in=unique_programs))))
```